# How to use ImageMagick in an AWS Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, binary, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to create a lambda that utilizes ImageMagick to convert PDF to images.

For this to work I can upload a binary of ImageMagick.

This approach fails as it seems there are some shared libraries IM depends on.

Is there a way to install ImageMagick either as a layer or get it all packaged up with its dependencies?
Or maybe a different solution all together is the right one.

Right now, I have verified I can upload binaries as part of a Lambda package and call them.

Answer (score 5):

There is [image-magick-lambda-layer](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications%7Eimage-magick-lambda-layer)

And there is a project to compile ImageMagick utilities for AWS Lambda - [ImageMagick for AWS Lambda](https://github.com/serverlesspub/imagemagick-aws-lambda-2)

There was this Youtube video i tried to follow (i didn't tried it myself) - [AWS Serverless Lambda Tutorial - How to Use ImageMagick with AWS Lambda?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMOJfemiC_w)

Comment: I should have pointed that I am aware of this. The PDF functionality is not built in this layer. 
I have solved this by getting a layer of ghostscript - this one works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

There is an [ImageMagick layer already built out there](https://github.com/serverlesspub/imagemagick-aws-lambda-2). It has many of the options already enabled, and if you use it as a shell command, it is runtime independent. Alas, it's PDF conversion functionality is missing. Was not built.
I have achieved my purpose by using a [layer that consists of GhostScript binary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgcyGI5X1G0&feature=em-share_video_user) `/opt/bin/gs`

Comment: Can you update the link of this GhostScript layer? It's pointing at the moment to a rather weird youtube video ...

Comment: ru telling me someone hacked SO?! I hope I can find that link again

Answer (score -1):

There is already a AWS lambda layer build available. Make sure you have docker first, then:

```
git clone https://github.com/serverlesspub/imagemagick-aws-lambda-2.git
cd imagemagick-aws-lambda-2
make all
```